# Put transition to hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this script in jquery which makes a hover image (in the hover replaces the images) .

The specific question is how do I place a transition ?

```
$( "figure.salud img" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( this ).attr("src","img/salud5.jpg");   
      },function() {
        $( this ).attr("src","img/salud5-gris.jpg");      
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something as this ,do let me know if something else was expected!

```js
$( ".salud img" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( this ).fadeOut(0).attr("src","https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/yahoo-logo.jpg").fadeIn(500);   
      },function() {
        $( this ).fadeOut(0).attr("src","http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg").fadeIn(500);      
      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="salud">
    <img src="http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg" width="160" height="160"/>
    
</div>
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/nhwuh7pb/9/

Comment: @user3810167 Another options as in? What kind of effect do you need?

Comment: What like a the transition??